# How do I make my balloon annotations circular instead of oval-shaped?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks

I'm getting oval balloons for my annotations instead of circular balloons even though I selected the circular setting.

[image: Balloon Settings]

Is there any way to edit/revert this annotation to become a normal circle?

Comment: Could you specify which version of solidworks you're using? That might help.

Comment: Googling the more general problem of "solidworks circle appears as ellipse" there's some discussion on the Solidworks forums involving [screen resolution settings](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/39397).

Comment: @Ethan48 I'm using Solidworks 2014

Comment: It looks like it's a circle in one plane but that plane is not perpendicular to the screen, as the annotation text is in the plane of the screen I'm tempted to think that this is a bug. Take a look at the annotation from different angles and see if it's circular when viewed from a different angle.